# Got ValueError while trying to track token usage in Langchain

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, chatgpt-api, py-langchain

I am following this tutorial from langchain official documentation [here](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/models/llms/token_usage_tracking) were I try to track the number of tokens while usage. However, I wanted to use gpt-3.5-turbo instead of text-davinci-003 so I changed the LLM class used from OpenAI to ChatOpenAI but this a Value Error of unsupported message type

Here is the code snippet:

```
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.callbacks import get_openai_callback

os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = "OPENAI-API-KEY"

llm = ChatOpenAI(
  model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo-16k',
  temperature=0.0
)

with get_openai_callback() as cb:
    result = llm("Tell me a joke")
    print(cb)
```

Getting this error:
`ValueError: Got unsupported message type: T`

Why changing the class from OpenAI to ChatOpenAI gives this error? How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are halfway through. If you type the question/query/prompt directly into a `ChatOpenAI` instance - `llm` in your case - you'll get an error.

Try this, based on LangChain's [example](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/models/chat/):

```
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.callbacks import get_openai_callback
from langchain.schema import AIMessage, HumanMessage, SystemMessage


os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = "OPENAI-API-KEY"

chat = ChatOpenAI(
  model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo', #Opinion: no need to use the -16k model
  temperature=0.0
)

with get_openai_callback() as cb:
    result = chat([HumanMessage(content="Tell me a joke.")]
    print(f"\n Total Tokens: {cb.total_tokens}")
    print(f" Prompt Tokens: {cb.prompt_tokens}")
    print(f" Completion Tokens: {cb.completion_tokens}")
    print(f" Total Cost (USD): ${round(cb.total_cost, 2)}")
```

Look at LangChain's [Python documentation](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/chat_models/langchain.chat_models.openai.ChatOpenAI.html#langchain.chat_models.openai.ChatOpenAI) for `ChatOpenAI` reference.

PS: With `temperature=0.0`, you'll likely get a quite dull joke.